# Не запускается встроенный эмулятор Android Studio

Tags: android, эмулятор

В общем, хочу запустить эмулятор Android Wear, создал виртуальное устройство, в Run Configuration выбираю модуль (wear) и запускаю - но ничего не происходит, в логах пусто, 0 реакции. Пробовал запустить сначала модуль (phone), а потом (wear) - тоже ничего, `phone` запускается, а `wear`. Есть подозрения что не хватает дискового пространства (осталось 2 гб на SSD), такое может быть?

При запуске эмулятора мобильного устройства вижу это:

`HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode`

Я так понимаю скорее в этом проблема!?

**UPD**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке изменить объем памяти допустим до 512 - оно вроде как сохраняет, но после этого в 'Size on disk' все равно пишет 1 gb

Comment: Cколько под эмуль оперативки выделили?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид теперь кажется вижу причину проблемы! что нужно сделать понизить количество выделеной памяти?  и почему в часах  может писать 'Failed to load' ?

Comment: Думается, что гиг для нексуса это минималка. А насчет ошибки - в SDK manager-e Android tools установили?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид да, я установи Intel HAXM и увеличил объем памяти с 512 до 1024, вроде все норм. Не понятно теперь только, модуль wear просто запустить на эмуляторе нельзя, нужно сначала запустить приложение на эмуляторе телефона, и через него установить приложение на эмулятор часов?

Comment: Незнаю даже. А памяти на Android wear гиг тоже выделен?

Comment: было 512, поставил 1гиг - ниче не изменилось. Пишет 'adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline', и экран часов черный.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152681/android-emulator-5554-offline вот тут гляньте. Может устраниться проблема

Comment: @АндроидАндроид да, я пробовал варианты оттуда, не помогло, утсройство все равно оффлайн.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема по которой не получалось запустить эмулятор часов, или запускался но с черным экраном и в offline заключалась в следующем:

1. SDK Tools: Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) - нужно было его установить и увеличить объем выделяемой памяти, что бы он был не меньше чем выделяется для вашего устройства в эмуляторе.
2. SDK Manager: Android Wear Intel x86Atom System Image - он должен быть установлен для конкретной версии 4.4,  5.0.1  и т.д. В моем случае я для часов устанавливал версию прошивки 5.0.1, а  Android Wear Intel x86Atom System Image  у меня был установлен только для 4.4, таким образом понизив версию прошивки для часов до 4.4 - проблема решилась. Думаю если бы я оставил на часах 5.0.1  и установил Android Wear Intel x86Atom System Image для этой же прошивки, результат был таким же.